# Trying to recall author/title of a book (or series) about person who becomes a policeman in a magical/dream world

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a book, or more likely a series of books from ~10 years ago (or more? Maybe they had been around longer and I just read them for the first time back then).

In the "dream" world, where magic is a thing, the chief of police "pulls" a man from our reality through into his reality, and recruits him to join the magical investigation force.

The other members of the team have various special powers, but I'm fuzzy on the details. One of them might have a magic "fist" of some sort.

The story follows the recruit through learning about various aspects of his new world (how magic works, what his power is, what the chief of police wants from him) and then follows the recruit and the team on various investigations. I'm not sure if these investigations were all in one book or spread across multiple books. If I recall correctly, magic is legally limited according to the amount of "power" you are allowed to use. The investigators look into situations where too much power is used, or something strange occurs that might involve disallowed types of magic.

I think the protagonist returns back to his mundane reality at the end of each investigation and one of the decisions he has to make is whether to break ties with our reality (and thus effectively die) so he can stay in the dream world permanently.

He falls in love with one of the other members of the team, but through some sort of miscommunication ends up meeting her at a "hookup spot" that somehow (magically) guarantees one-night-stands only, so their relationship has to remain professional-only after that.

One of the investigations involves following an import/export business to try to find out where they are getting their goods from, which turns out to be an imaginary world.

The vehicles in the dreamworld are powered/controlled by willpower, so our protagonist is able to drive the vehicles more quickly and is more maneuverable than others.

I think one of the investigations involves a series of murders where people are turned into tasty dinner dishes. The chef at a local restaurant turns out to be the murderer, but he is in turn murdered in the same fashion by the spouse (?) of one of the victims.

I think the protagonist learns that his special power is that he is a "magical vampire" and can suck the magical power out of others.

I have a vague recollection that the author was Russian and that the books I was reading were translations, but I may be thinking of another series.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: until the last 3/4 paragraphs this sounds quite a lot like the Void Trilogy: protagonist lives in a sort of dream world, has powers somewhat tied to willpower, becomes a policeman and catches feelings for one of his team members. This of course falls short at the chef and vampire details.